# Python : How to assign ranks to categorical variables within a group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given I have a dataset containing only the first two columns, how do I create another column using Python which will contain the rank based on these ranges for each group separately. My desired output would look like this -

| id | range | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-20 | 2 |
| 1 | 20-30 | 3 |
| 1 | 5-10 | 1 |
| 2 | 20-30 | 2 |
| 2 | 10-20 | 1 |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 10-20 | 2 |
| 3 | 5-10 | 1 |
| 3 | 20-30 | 3 |
| 3 | 30+ | 4 |

NOTE - These are the only 4 ranges [5-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30+] that can belong to any id at max. There can be blanks as well For example as given in the reproducible example, if for id 2 there are two ranges 10-20 and 20-30 the corresponding to 10-20 the rank will be 1 and corresponding to 20-30 the rank will be 2. I have checked that df.groupby can be used but I am not being able to figure out how in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your range column to a category dtype before apply `rank`:

```
df['range'] = df['range'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(
                  ['5-10', '10-20', '20-30', '30+'], ordered=True))

df['rank'] = df.groupby('id')['range'].apply(lambda x: x.rank())
```

```
>>> df
   id  range  rank
0   1  10-20   2.0
1   1  20-30   3.0
2   1   5-10   1.0
3   2  20-30   2.0
4   2  10-20   1.0
5   2    NaN   NaN
6   3  10-20   2.0
7   3   5-10   1.0
8   3  20-30   3.0
9   3    30+   4.0
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
and after removing 'str' I am getting this error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()`?

Comment: output is - <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>.
I have also edited the dataset a little bit for the purpose of giving a better reproducible example

Comment: ```for j in range(len(df)):
    df['rank'] = int(df['range'][j][0])```


Trying to use something like this for the time being..running into issues with None values

Comment: Your sample should be representative of your real data.

Comment: It is now..sorry for the troubles.,I missed to check for blanks. It would be great if you can help me.

Comment: I updated my answer. While there are NaN values, you cannot convert rank to an integer.